# USB power on Windows Vista and Windows 7 but not on Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, usb

Why is it that when using Windows Vista or Windows 7 and I eject my USB device safely it’s still powered?

When using a flash drive I can still see the light, and when I use my [Western Digital Passport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Digital#2000s), that is USB powered, I can still feel the hard disk drive spinning. Yet, when I use Windows XP this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because it keeps power supplied but safely removes the catch of the computer. This is not a problem at all. After removing the drive safely (by right clicking), you can pull out the drive at any time and it won't get corrupt.